Spring Boot configuration file field encryption
I have a Spring Boot based application that is posting a listen on a port with SSL and associated keystore and trust store. I have a class that decrypts the fields that contain the passwords for those stores. I have tested the class at runtime and it works, but when I go to actually encrypt the fields in the file, the application fails at runtime. I am encapsulating my encrypted fields with ENC() and decrypting with the following class:
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        logger.debug("Processing property value: {}", originalValue);

        if (originalValue != null && originalValue.startsWith("ENC(") && originalValue.endsWith(")")) {
            final String encryptedValue = originalValue.substring(4, originalValue.length() - 1);

            try {
                final String encryptionKey = System.getenv("ENCRYPTION_KEY");
                if (encryptionKey == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("ENCRYPTION_KEY environment variable is not set.");
                }

                final String decryptedValue = CryptoUtil.decrypt(encryptedValue, encryptionKey);
                logger.debug("Decrypted value: {}", decryptedValue);
                return decryptedValue;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Failed to decrypt property value: {}", originalValue, e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to decrypt property value", e);
            }
        }
        return originalValue;
    }
}

My question is there a better way to perform this? I don't have a remote vault available just yet. I am wondering if anyone has done this in a similar fashion.
I put debug methods in my main class that verified the keystore/truststore was found, that SslBundle was loading, the encrypted value was being found in the file, and it was decrypted properly. That all worked but depending on which field I choose to encrypt to test, the application fails on that field.
